# Transfering a call to a different user agent registered with the same account on the Twilio SIP domain w. Grandstream phones

Tags: twilio, sip

I have three phones registered as +1xxxxxxxxxx (same account) on a Twilio SIP domain. When a call comes in all phones ring, which is the desired behavior. Next I'd like to either:

- transfer the call from the phone that initially answered the call to one of the other phones
- or short of that, re-ring the call on all phones to allow a different one to pick it up

I'm hoping there's a way to accomplish this in general, but specific info. on how to accomplish it using Grandstream phones would be appreciated above and beyond.